# Why can't I pass this variable between methods in a class? "missing 1 required positional argument"

Tags: python, tkinter, methods

I am trying to pass the hours variable from the GetHours function into the CSVtablemaker function but it gives me the error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "\\Marge\Users\14\CharKall14\My Documents\Year 13\Computing\Programming Project\[MAIN] FILE v3.py", line 81, in <lambda>
    self.Hours1Entry = tk.Button(frameHours, text="1 Hour", command= lambda: self.GetHours(1))
TypeError: GetHours() missing 1 required positional argument: 'hours'
```

I looked at tons of pages trying to find an answer to this, and it's probably pretty simple but I just don't get it. Sorry for my poor coding, I'm still pretty new.

Here's the whole class as it may not make sense without it:

````
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = tk.LabelFrame(master, text="Main Menu", padx=100, pady=10)
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)
        # Create timetable button
        createTimetable = tk.Button(frame, text="Create Timetable", command=self.CreateTimetable)
        createTimetable.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        # Exit program button
        exitProgram = tk.Button(frame, text="Exit Program", command=self.CloseWindow)
        exitProgram.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.hours = None

    def CloseWindow(self):
        # Closes the window when the close button is pressed
        root.destroy()

    def GetSubjects(self):
        # Retrieves the subjects from what the user enters in the tableWindow
        self.subject1 = self.subject1entry.get()
        self.subject2 = self.subject2entry.get()
        self.subject3 = self.subject3entry.get()
        print(self.subject1)
        print(self.subject2)
        print(self.subject3)

    def GetHours(self, numhours, hours):
        if numhours == 1:
            self.hours = 1
        elif numhours == 2:
            self.hours = 2
        elif numhours == 3:
            self.hours = 3
        else:
            print("unexpected error")

    def CreateTimetable(self):
        tableWindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
        tableWindow.title('Timetable Maker Window')
        tableWindow.geometry("800x500+400+200")
        tableFrame = tk.LabelFrame(tableWindow, text="Enter Subjects", padx=100, pady=10)
        tableFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)
        # Subject labels
        subjectlabel1 = tk.Label(tableFrame, text="Enter your first subject:")
        subjectlabel2 = tk.Label(tableFrame, text="Enter your second subject:")
        subjectlabel3 = tk.Label(tableFrame, text="Enter your third subject:")
        # Subject entry boxes
        self.subject1entry = tk.Entry(tableFrame)
        self.subject2entry = tk.Entry(tableFrame)
        self.subject3entry = tk.Entry(tableFrame)
        # Puts subject entry boxes on screen
        self.subject1entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.subject2entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.subject3entry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=4, pady=4)
        # Puts subject labels on screen
        subjectlabel1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        subjectlabel2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        subjectlabel3.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        # Creates subject confirm button
        subjectConfirm = tk.Button(tableFrame,text="Press to confirm subjects", command=self.GetSubjects)
        # Puts subject confirm button on screen
        subjectConfirm.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        frameHours = tk.LabelFrame(tableWindow, text="Hours tab", padx=100, pady=10)
        frameHours.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)
        self.Hours1Entry = tk.Button(frameHours, text="1 Hour", command= lambda: self.GetHours(1))
        self.Hours1Entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.Hours2Entry = tk.Button(frameHours, text="2 Hours", command= lambda: self.GetHours(2))
        self.Hours2Entry.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.Hours3Entry = tk.Button(frameHours, text="3 Hours", command= lambda: self.GetHours(3))
        self.Hours3Entry.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        

    def CSVtablemaker(self, hours):
        hour_val = self.hours
        while hour_val == 1:
            print("woo hoo it works")```
````

Answer (score 2):

Your GetHours method requires 3 arguments, but the lambda function gives only one.

```
def GetHours(self, numhours, hours)
```

...

```
command= lambda: self.GetHours(1)
```

The input "1" goes as the parameter "numhours". The other required parameter "hours" is not given.

--

Looking at your GetHours function, it looks like the extra input parameter "hours" is not used. You should be able to fix your issue by removing it as an input parameter when defining the method.